# Highlight table row depending on another cell's value

Tags: excel, format, row, highlight

I have a table with a set of rows and information on several countries. The countries are in the first column of the table. I would like to highlight a table row depending on the country selected in another sheet.

The table is in Sheet "Rankings" and the country is selected in Sheet "Report", on cell B4.

I have tried conditional formatting but it only highlights the first cell on the table (not the entire row) and it only does that if the country chosen is the one that appears first on the table.

I guess what I would need is a formula that would run through the first column of the table, detect the row in which the country selected is and then highlight that entire table row.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: "it only highlights the first cell" - you are probably missin $ somewhere in your conditional formatting formula, and what do you mean "country selected in another sheet" ?

Comment: I am not missing the $ - I am locking the column and leaving the row unlocked.
By "country selected in another sheet" I mean the country name written inanother cell in another sheet.

Comment: I tried this formula `=$A2=Arkusz2!$A$1` and works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been strongly hinted at in the comments above. However, I'll spell it out

1. On sheet `Rankings` select all the rows where the country names might appear in the first column
2. Open the New Formatting Rule dialog by selecting Conditional Formatting/New Rule from the Home tab of the ribbon
3. In "Select a Rule Type" (top part of dialog) select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" - the bottom part of the dialog will change
4. In the box labelled "Format values where this formula is true:" enter `=$A1=Report!$B$4`
5. Click the "Format" button, choose a suitable format and return to the New Formatting Rule" dialog and click OK

Step 4., assumes that the first row selected in step 1. is Row 1. If this is not the case, the formula in step 4. should be changed to reflect the correct first row. For example if you have headers in Row 1 of sheet `Rankings` and the first row that contains a country is Row 2 then change the formula to `=$A2=Report!$B$4`.

If you use the "point and click" method of building the formula in step 4., Excel uses absolute addresses and it will create a subtly different formula which will not give you the results you desire.